# Do the same as File>>Export Map>>Save as PDF with a Python command in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, export, pdf

I have a Python script to apply IDW interpolation over different datasets, so that the results are several rasters in format .aux.

How can I save automatically in the Python script what appears in the page layout (in my case, the GPS points and the raster map) to a PDF directly, as I would manually do going to the File section and clicking in Export Map?

It has to be easy but I am not finding the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ExportToPDF](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopdf.htm).

From the help:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"C:\Project\Output\Project.pdf")
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! What I finally did was take the current mxd in my screen: mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") and then export it arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"C:\Project\Output\Project.pdf")

Comment: Great @IceBelt. Please mark the answer as correct.